# Is a 9000 BTU split heat pump oversized for cooling a 156 square feet room (Quebec climate)?

Tags: heat-pump, cooling

I want to cool a single bedroom during the sumer with a split heatpump.

I will only run it during the night, with door closed because I don't mind heat during the day, I just have a hard time sleeping with a high temperature. I will also NOT use it for heating, even if possible, I only want cooling.

I have tried many sizing calculators, methods, spreadsheets, etc, and for the room size of 156 square feet (13x12 with 9 feet ceiling), the prescribed BTU requirements range from aprox 3000 to 6000 BTUs.

The discrepancy in the prescribed estimates is disconcerting in itself, but understandable, given that some calculators have more parameters than others.

After a bit of shopping, it appears that split heat pumps don't come smaller than 9000 BTUs

Given that all calculators prescribe cooling capacity significantly lower than 9000 BTU, would it be a mistake to install such a unit ? Will I get the inconvenients of an oversized system ?

Comment: Actual load depends strongly on insulation, and insolation, which are too often either assumed or poorly allowed for in most calculators. I've definitely seen 6000 BTU mini-splits, (In the Northeastern USA) seems odd the Canadian market would be THAT different. A good inverter-drive unit should operate from roughly 25% of load to 100% without (inefficent) stopping and starting, by varying the compressor speed. But since load also depends on outside temperature you still want one "just big enough" ideally.

Comment: This isn't a shopping SE but I can tell you that Mitsubishi makes a 6k sized unit.

Answer (score 4):

Oversized is *good* in a mini-split.

### Who cares?  "Oversized" is not a modern concept.

It's a mini-split with a variable speed drive.  All the hand-wringing about over-sizing A/C units *only applies to "That 70's Air Conditioner" with its obsolete "bang-bang" controls*.

[Ka-chunk BRZZZZZZZZ](https://youtu.be/43XKfuptnik?t=2279)

Remember that from your childhood?  That's bang-bang controls.  Make a hard start at (setpoint), run at absolute maximum (damn the efficiency) and then hard shut-off at (setpoint + hysteresis).  A desperate scheme in an age before silicon electronics made controls and variable drives possible.

If "That 70's Unit" bangs-off too soon, it hasn't circulated enough air to do a good job **dehumidifying** it.  And dehumidified air feels cooler, so it helps.  Sellers of That 70's bang-bang unit are thus concerned about sizing.  That's not a problem for a unit that runs continuously.

**These modern units will simply run at a lower (quieter) setting continuously, and this, dehumidification won't be affected**.

However, "oversized" will result in slower (quieter) cruising, faster arrival at desired temperature, and better performance in heat mode. So Ashton Kutcher can suck it :)

### It's oversized... *for cooling*

But that doesn't matter on a variable-speed mini-split.  Your indoor unit *actually talks to* the outdoor unit in a more sophisticated way than "on" or "off".  Your compressor and both fans will vary speed - and that means an "oversized" unit runs *quieter*.

But why not use it for heating?  It's like printing free money.  You're getting 2-6 watts of heat for 1 watt of power.  Even if you normally heat with gas, unless it's one of the coldest days of the year, the mini-split will give more heat per dollar than the gas furnace will.  Possibly even the coldest day of the year - these modern mini-splits can perform *that well* because they aren't designed in the, um, 70's.

If you heard some crud about heat pumps needing emergency heat for cold days, that's "That 70's talk".  Back in the 70s, the US government prodded domestic A/C makers to investigate adding a $50 reversing valve, and the manufacturers slow-walked it, and came up with a heat pump with limited cold-weather performance.  *It's almost like they were trying to fail*.  Your unit will work down to quite cold, though COP and throughput will suffer. But this is where oversizing works in your favor.

Comment: people who buy things and don't have unlimited funds care.

Comment: @TigerGuy wow, you downvote for that?  I think the answer has good value for breaking a myth about heat pump design.  You're my first DV in a month... hair-trigger downvotes over a petty snark is NOT the norm on DIY, or most of Stackexchange really.  Take that to Reddit where it belongs.

Comment: My hunch about the heating is: OP rents in a building that doesn't provide air conditioning but provides heating in a non-measured way - e.g., a big boiler for the whole building. In which case OP wouldn't want to spend *anything* on the heating side of things (except as an emergency backup) because inefficient free heat is cheaper than efficient paying for heat.

Comment: Sounds quite reasonable, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, except that all the "free `x`" arguments in the world forget that _someone_ is paying for it. That "free" heat is included in the OPs rent, just like "free" shipping is included in Amazon Prime pricing...

Comment: @FreeMan True, but. Let's say OP is one of 8 apartments, each requiring roughly comparable heat. Plus let's say OP's space is actually 3x the 156 square feet, because OP is only bothering with the heat pump for the bedroom and not for kitchen/bathroom/living room/dining room. And let's say (no guarantee actually) that OP can shut off heat to their entire apartment - 1/8 of the building. Using some simple numbers: $1,000 energy cost to heat the entire building. OP's nominal share is $125. But landlord will look at this and say "I'm not in your apartment, how do I know you're not cheating"

Comment: So if landlord gives OP a $125 discount in high heating season (and proportionately less in others - based perhaps on Heating Degree Days, so a *mess* to calculate) then OP is great. But if landlord says "you're crazy, maybe you're cheating, but I'll split it", then OP is paying $62.50 to landlord and, nominally $20 to heat their own place (modern heat pump could easily be 3x as fuel efficient as an old boiler) then they save money. Except of course if they don't have a separate electric meter, in which case the landlord will (somewhat correctly) "I'm now going to pay more for electric so why"

Comment: "should I give you a break on oil". Many other possible variations. But bottom line is that there are scenarios where heat pump for heating will make a **lot** of sense and others where, particularly due to shared and/or hidden costs, it doesn't. Yes it almost always does from an environmental perspective, but unless the environmentalists are paying my fuel bill that doesn't really matter so much.

Comment: Yeah, but is the landlord really going to lower rent because his actual heating bill went down last year? Didn't think so.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica buying more than you need and more than the spec is bad engineering and bad advice.  Oversize is mitigated by good performance at lower speed in variable speed units, but it certainly isn't "good."  You don't buy a D8 tractor when you need a D6.  Feel free to argue for the heat pump, but that wasn't in the spec.

Comment: @TigerGuy Giving people more options is a "style of answer" question and there isn't a right or wrong answer there.  I'm sorry you feel that way, but downvoting for that is uncalled for by the standards of this forum.  I ask you to at least retract it.   Overpower has its advantages, such as quicker regain to target temperature, and good performance in unusual "100 year" weather events like we have every. year these days.  It also covers cases the formulas don't, like higher-than-average solar gain. OP seems to understand they're buying a lot, they don't need an education there.

Answer (score 2):

#### It's oversized

> I have tried many sizing calculators, methods, spreadsheets, etc, and for the room size of 156 square feet (13x12 with 9 feet ceiling), the prescribed BTU requirements range from aprox 3000 to 6000 BTUs.

You have your answer.  Most well-built split systems run quite well at lower loads, but you're paying for more capacity than you need.  Paying for a heat pump is additional cost as well.

Comment: You haven't told OP anything they don't already know.  Further, you're advising them to rely on "square foot based" formulas, and while that is a "gold standard in the industry", it's a rather substandard one, since it fails to take into account the top influences on HVAC requirement: Solar gain, and insulation.  Square footage is a distant third. Units sized to formula either underperform or overperform depending on those factors.  OP knows their building and site better than the formula does.

Answer (score 0):

Most 9k mini split single units will throttle down to about 2000 or 3000 btu. Probably the right size for 150sqft.